# Connecting Dynamic Crm 2015 from ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm

I am absolutely new with Dynamic CRM. I need to connect one of the online instance of it Dynamic CRM 2015. I was provided SDK and walkthrough. On testing on walkthrough when I change the web config with my details it is generating exception as
"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Stack Trace Shows:

[InvalidOperationException: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://xxyy.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0'.]

when I am trying with browser I get back the result with the same URL:

https://xxyy.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0

My connectionString as follows:

```
<add name="Xrm" connectionString="Server=https://xxyy.crm5.dynamics.com; Domain=xxyy; Username=abc@xxyy.onmicrosoft.com; Password=abc@123456;" />
```

Any Suggestion.... thanks

Comment: remove the domain from your connection string

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the Connection String for Dynamics CRM Online should look like this:

> Url=https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com; Username=jsmith@contoso.onmicrosoft.com; Password=passcode;

Only 3 parameters are needed:

- Url
- Username
- Password

Your Connection string should look like this:

> Url=https://xxyy.crm5.dynamics.com; Username=abc@xxyy.onmicrosoft.com; Password=abc@123456;

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695810.aspx#examples)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for connection:

**Declare Globally:**

```
string username = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
string password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
string serviceUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrganizationServiceUri"];
```

**Use this function for connection**

```
public void ConnectToMSCRM(string UserName, string Password, string ServiceUri)
{
    try
    {
        ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
        credentials.UserName.UserName = UserName;
        credentials.UserName.Password = Password;
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri(ServiceUri);
        OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(serviceUri, null, credentials, null);
        proxy.EnableProxyTypes();
        _service = (IOrganizationService)proxy;
        Response.Write("\n Connected to CRM \n\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("\n Error is :  \n\n" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```